# url rewriting in asp.net 4.0: A route named 'xxxxx' could not be found in the route collection

Tags: asp.net

The error I'm getting is

```
A route named 'xxxxx' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name
```

***global asax***

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("test2-testurl", "test2/{category}", "~/test2.aspx");
    }
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        // Code that runs on application startup

    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

</script>
```

In page `test1` I have coded below like this on button click event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = Page.GetRouteUrl("test2-testurl", new { category = "laptops" });
    Response.RedirectToRoute(url);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this (remove 'test2'):

```
routes.MapPageRoute("test2-testurl", "{category}", "~/test2.aspx");
```

**Update:**
try just to redirect to page this way

```
Response.Redirect("page2/laptops");
```

Example:

```
// add route
routes.MapPageRoute("ad-view", "view/{ad-id}", "~/ad_view.aspx");
// on page I usualy bind values in repeater to links like this:
<asp:HyperLink ID="TitleHL" NavigateUrl='<%# "view/" + Eval("ad_id") %>' runat="server">
// to redirect from code-behind i'll use:
Responce.Redirect("view/" + ad_id);
```

Comment: do i need to add something in web.config file along with programming since im still getting error like the resource cannot be found.

Comment: looks like something is wrong with the link itself, can you post it here?

Comment: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.  Requested url:test2/laptops/

Comment: obviously there should be something wrong with the test2.aspx page itself. play around here. double check page name, maybe try to rebuild the project, enter url directly into browser. you probably missing something small - should be very silly issue.

Comment: can you please give me a demo of this not from your site but made by you i would be happy to learn from that ...

Comment: example added above. if you stuck, i'll suggest you to create new test solution, add simple page, add route and try if its working. then if yes, compare with your current project and find a difference.